# Pytest multiple test runs with parameterize

Tags: python, pytest

How can I use @pytest.mark.parameterize for running a test multple times. Something other than hard coded range. I'd like the times to be an env. var

Comment: Can you say anything more about why you'd like to run them multiple times? Do they sometimes fail? In that case, that's called a [flaky test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/flaky.html) and there are existing tools to handle those.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [pytest-repeat](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-repeat/) instead of `pytest.mark.parametrize`

> `pytest-repeat` is a plugin for pytest that makes it easy to repeat a single test, or multiple tests, a specific number of times.

A minimal example would be:

```
import os
n_repeats = os.environ["PYTEST_REPEATS"]

@pytest.mark.repeat(n_repeats)
def test_something():
    ...
```

`pytest.mark.parametrize` would be used to run the test across multiple parameter sets (i.e. different test inputs for each run)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.environ` to manually pass environment variables to `@pytest.mark.parameterize`.

Or, use something like [pytest-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-dotenv/) if you'd like the fancier solution.

Comment: how can I use it here? @pytest.mark.parametrize("execution_number", )